# Jenkins Plugin - Send environment variable values to Jenkins Instance - AbstractBuild/Run

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm developing new Jenkins plugin for sending Jenkins build & SCM [Git] notification to external system,

With the FreeStyleProject, I can able to send the GIT details [GIT_COMMIT,GIT_BRANCH,GIT_URL] to external system.

Inside my plugin code, I fetched these Git details using Environment details [see. below snip] which is set by Git plugin.

```
<snip>
   Run run -> Passed on the fly from JobListener;
   EnvVars env  = run.getEnvironment(listener);
   env.get("GIT_URL");
   env.get("GIT_COMMIT");
</snip>
```

So the above snip works fine with FreeStyleProject.

But unable to get the Environment variables of the GIT details in Pipeline projects.

Is there a way to inject/Pass the GIT details as Environment variables into my plugin system?

Is there a way to inject/pass, pipeline groovy script variables into running Jenkins instance AbstractBuild/Run/TaskListener object?

Thanks